# Exec command do not work?

Tags: php, exec

Trying to convert my video using php and ffmpeg but below code doesn't give me any result or output file? Do you know why and what I am doing wrong? I should have test.webm file in return but do not have it :-(

```
<?php
 exec("ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -ab 96k -b:v 700k -ar 44100 -s 640x480  test.webm");
?>
```

Comment: try specifying absolute paths (for the command and the output) .. and how are you expecting to "have the test.webm file in return" ????

Comment: Is ffmpeg in the PATH? Add two variables as parameters to `exec` and `var_dump()` them after the call.

Comment: Does `exec()` return something? Please post result of `echo exec()`.

Comment: ffmpeg and test.mp4 are in the same location http://localhost/

Comment: once I echo that, I do not have anything in return :-(

Comment: "Does not work" is not an valid PHP error message.

Comment: no error message, empty blank page. Even after adding full path doesn't do the job.

Answer (score 2):

**Nailing down exec() problems:**

I'd suggest you to check what `exec()` is giving back:

```
echo exec(...);
```

Sure, it may happen that `ffmpeg` is simply not in your `PATH`. In this case `exec()` will clearly state about this, and you might need to provide the absolute path to `ffmpeg`, i.e.:

*Linux:*

```
exec("/path/to/ffmpeg ...");
```

*Windows:*

```
exec("c:\\path\\to\\ffmpeg ...");
```

**Background task:**

Other concern is that `ffmpeg` might run for a pretty long time, which might lead to a timeout. To avoid this problem you can execute `ffmpeg` in a background by adding `&` at the end of your command, or, for Windows, adding `cmd /C` in front of your actual command:

*Linux:*

```
exec("ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -ab 96k -b:v 700k -ar 44100 -s 640x480 test.webm &");
```

*Windows:*

```
exec("cmd /C ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -ab 96k -b:v 700k -ar 44100 -s 640x480 test.webm");
```

In this case `exec()` will return immediately, leaving `ffmpeg()` running in the background. `ffmpeg()` process will terminate as soon as it has done it's execution. But sure, you need to implement some sort of monitoring mechanism, if you want to notify the user that conversion is completed and converted file is available for download.

Comment: still do not do antyhing, even once use echo to print:

Comment: <?php
 exec("ffmpeg -i C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.mp4 -ab 96k -b:v 700k -ar 44100 -s 640x480 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.webm &");
?>

Comment: Please try this instead: `<?php exec("ffmpeg -i C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\test.mp4 -ab 96k -b:v 700k -ar 44100 -s 640x480 C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\test.webm"); ?>`. Use double slashes on Windows!

Comment: here you go: exec output: exec returned: 1array dump:array(0) { }

Comment: ...and no *test.wbm* is present in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\?

Comment: Also, for your information: in Windows return code 1 means following: `Error: 1 Incorrect function : Action has attempted to execute non-recognized command in Windows command prompt cmd.exe.`. Please double check what your are executing! Perhaps there is missing slashes - you need to use double ones.

Comment: So, does it work? Missing slashes? Please accept the answer if the problem was solved. Thanks.

Comment: as you can see all the slashes are in place and still don't have my output file :-( I will accept right away once it's sorted.